# Using require() calls in the console

Tags: browserify

I am using Browserify to build a react app where I am using CommonJS modules. When testing the app, I would sometimes like to have access to some module in the build, but whenever I try to use require from the console in Chrome it fails.

```
require('react-router')
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'react-router'
```

Is there a way to `require` modules dynamically?

Of course, I understand I can only require modules that have been built into the bundle by browserify ...

Comment: I seem to be able to `require('react')`, but not any other modules.